# Data structure to work with several matrices in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, data-structures

I have 4 folders (experiments), each of them contains 3 files. 1 - matrix of number, 2/3 - row/column names.

I would like to work with all 4 of them in one moment. For example, plot every matrix in subplot. Compare matrix 1 and 2. And etc.

I do not want to hardcode all variable names like experiment1, ... . I would prefer to use some list of matrices.

Thus, the question is: what would be a good data structure for such analysis?

I am thinking about every matrix - panda data frame, with correspoinding row/column names. And combine them in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet all you want is hdf5 file format (Hierarchical Data Format). The format is quite well supported on the level of different programming languages like C++, Python or Julia.